# Angular. Is there way to access variable in *ngFor in ts file?

Tags: angular

Let's say I have such temlape

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    </div>
```

So is it possible to access somehow the **item** var in ts file?

Yeah I know that I can assign eventListener like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="handleClick(item)">
        </div>
```

But I need to access the var **item** in the moment of its creation

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @yurzui, well I need to use it in my ts file =)

Comment: So how do you determin **which** item you want in the TS file?

Comment: @AT82, well as I wrote above I can access item var for example with click listener, I need similar way but at the moment of creation( assignment ) of variable item

Comment: That is what I was trying to figure out... What do you really want to do. Since if you iterate through a list, WHICH item in the list should be assigned? Could you please show all the relevant code... what is inside that div? How does your TS look like? I think this is a XY problem'...

Answer (score 0):

No, **item** cannot used directly in ts file. Used this way,
HTML file:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onClick(item)"></div>
```

.ts file:

```
onClick(item: any) {
  // Used item
}
```

- Any event used to get item based on requirement.